# How to check if the user had already like the comment

Tags: mysql, api, web-services, facebook-like

I am designing a 'http api' for client app, it about comment,the situation is that if the app user logged in, he could likes some comments and unlike them,but they can not like twice or more times, so every time when the app get the comments data from my 'http api', the data should be able to tell the client app if the comment had already be liked by the user.
Well, I have implement the api recently,but I found it works not well, my design is:

**Insert:**
I created a table 'Comment' for saving comment(content, created time and so on) a table'User' for app user, and a table 'Like' for recording the info of which user liked which comment
When user like a comment:
1, increase the the record 'like_counts' in table 'comment'
2, insert into table Like set user='the user' and comment='the comment'

**Query:**

1. Query the comment list from mysql (about 20 records every page)
2. Foreach very comment and query from table Like where comment=='the comment' and user='the user'
3. if the query result is exist in step 2, that means the user had liked the comment before.

The matter is when the client get the comments for one page,that mean I have to execute 20 queries with table 'Like' to check if the user had liked it before, that will be very bad design, I think. I know that I could use some cache, like Redis, It's the next step, I want to know what's the good way for mysql way?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` in your query to get the information from the `Like` table for the user at the same time as you get the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Mr Barmar,LEFT JOIN will save my query counts,it maybe the most effective way to work,Thank you very much. BTW,is't the common way to do in this situation?^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the comments are stored in a table and as such will have a comment_id.

Same for user with a user_id.

The likes are stored in a table named Likes and has 2 columns: user_id and comment_id.  both as a foreign key to the comments-table and the user-table.

Together they form the primary key in the table Likes. Thus preventing duplicates.

Should user 123 want to like comment 1000 again, it will result in a duplicate key error for 123-1000 combination.
So your application will not need to check before inserting: the insert will simply fail. To your application the task to recognize that error message and give the error message

Comment: Yeah,it will defined bad 'like' automatically when insert into the table "like",but nouse for query...

Comment: I understood you needed this information to know if the insert was allowed. But you need it also per record in te long lists? A left join would then be the way, as suggested above by Barmar